# WCF contracts async service vs async client

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

**Q:** Is there any difference for the client between WCF async service call and async client call?

Right now I have a contract that looks like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFoo
{        
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetFoo();

    [OperationContract]
    FooResult EndGetFoo(IAsyncResult asyncResult);  

    ...
}
```

And I was thinking to refactor it to something like this (and just call it asynchronously later from a WPF client).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFoo
{        
    [OperationContract]
    FooResult GetFoo(); 

    ...
}
```

The reason is that I want to simplify service contract for the client.

Comment: My understanding may be wrong but AFAIU, SCENARIO1, BeginGetFoo is called from the client to the server to start a job and returns immediately. When the client is ready to read the result, it calls EndGetFoo and the connection holds until the request is sent back (a timeout could occur here).

In SCENARIO2, the client uses a local async method to call the server, immediatly returned as a task. Then the client does some job and finally awaits its task to complete. BUT, during all that time, the connection was active which should change something on the timeout delay, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's essentially no difference (if it's written correctly - notice the corrected signature below: the Begin operation needs to take an `AsyncCallback` and an `object` parameter, and the End operation must not be decorated with `[OperationContract]`). If you want to handle the threading yourself, then feel free to declare it as a synchronous operation; if you want to let WCF handle that, then go with the async pattern. But the request which the client will send to the server is the same in both cases.

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface IFoo 
{         
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)] 
    IAsyncResult BeginGetFoo(AsyncCallback callback, object state); 
    FooResult EndGetFoo(IAsyncResult asyncResult);   

    ... 
}
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to have a 'simple' interface for the client when using task-based async implementation (i.e. where the operation declares its return type as Task<T>). The difference there is that all the examples I have seen only have one method declared for the operation (rather than 2 as above) and that one method has a return type of Task<T> -- which would seem to imply that the client is going to receive a result of Task<T>, which I would like to avoid.